# iOS Parsing text file Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parsing

I try to parse my txt file, i have question and 5 answers in txt file, and i want to save question to separate variable, and similar answers.

My code:

```
do {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "txt")
        let source = try? String.init(contentsOfFile: path!)
        var elements = source?.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        var parsedObject = [[String: String]]()

        for i in 0..<(elements?.count)! - 1 {
            let objects = [String : String]()
            let element = elements![i]
            //print(element)

            let objectsElement = element.components(separatedBy: "\r")
            let question = objectsElement[0]
            let answer1 = objectsElement[1]
            let answer2 = objectsElement[2]
            let answer3 = objectsElement[3]
            let anserr4 = objectsElement[4]
            let answer5 = objectsElement[5]

            print(question, answer1, answer2, answer3, anserr4, answer5)
            print(objectsElement)


        }

    }
```

Error which i received:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

If i comment this code:

```
 let question = objectsElement[0]
            let answer1 = objectsElement[1]
            let answer2 = objectsElement[2]
            let answer3 = objectsElement[3]
            let anserr4 = objectsElement[4]
            let answer5 = objectsElement[5]

            print(question, answer1, answer2, answer3, anserr4, answer5)
```

I will get such output:

[image]

Structure file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ah1Mk_WY3b_qbqKM18nxxPT1rNXFiISa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You really should use JSON instead of txt, the system already have parser support for it, it will makes everything much easier

Comment: How i can transform txt file to JSON?

Comment: I have 20 000 rows of data in txt file, if it's possible to transform to JSON i will really  happy

Comment: I put full file, in which you can see structure

Comment: @Andrew Could you show an excerpt of the contents of the `txt` file?

Comment: @Carpsen90 i add link for google disk, with structure of file

Comment: @Carpsen9 if shorted, i have question, and five answers

Comment: @Andrew The link takes to a `docx` file. Did you manually add `\n` and `\r`?
Can I see a sample of the `txt` file

Comment: @Carpsen90 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mRYRzCqbjX04mR6mhXBljImvYgStqnFF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Andrew have a look at my answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case one way to achieve what you want is this:

```
do {

      let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Data", ofType: "txt")
      let source = try? String.init(contentsOfFile: path!)
      var elements = source?.components(separatedBy: "\n\n") // Here is the change
      var parsedObject = [[String: String]]()

      for i in 0..<(elements?.count)! - 1 {
          let objects = [String : String]()
          let element = elements![i]

          let objectsElement = element.components(separatedBy: "\n") // And Here
          if objectsElement.count > 1 {
              let question = objectsElement[0]
              let answer1 = objectsElement[1]
              let answer2 = objectsElement[2]
              let answer3 = objectsElement[3]
              let answer4 = objectsElement[4]
              let answer5 = objectsElement[5]

              print("Question: \(question)")
              print("Answer: \(answer1)")
              print("Answer: \(answer2)")
              print("Answer: \(answer3)")
              print("Answer: \(answer4)")
              print("Answer: \(answer5)")
          }
      }
}
```

If you are not changing your text file format then in this way you can get the solution. For now you can try this solution but search for better one or if I will get one I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 4):

Parsing a text file is very, very tedious.

Here is a quick&dirty converter from your .txt file to JSON using regular expression.

The JSON dictionaries have the format

- `question` (`String`), the question text
- `answers`(`[String]`), an array of answers
- `correctAnswerIndex` (`Int`), the zero-based index of the correct answer in `answers`
- `number` (`Int`), the question number.

The regex pattern searches for

- one or more digits **or** one letter in range `A...E` (is captured) - `(\\d+|[A-E])`
- followed by a dot and a whitespace character - `\\.\\s`
- followed by one or more arbitrary characters (is captured) - `(.+)`

---

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "txt")!
let string = try! String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)

let pattern = "(\\d+|[A-E])\\.\\s(.+)"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
var result = [[String:Any]]()
var question = [String:Any]()
var answers = [String]()
var answerCounter = 0

let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..<string.endIndex, in: string))
for match in matches {
    let index = string[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!]
    var text = string[Range(match.range(at: 2), in: string)!]
    if let ordinal = Int(index) {
        question["number"] = ordinal
        question["question"] = text
    } else {
        if text.hasPrefix("*") {
            text = text.dropFirst()
            question["correctAnswerIndex"] = answerCounter
        }
        answers.append(String(text))
        answerCounter += 1
        if answerCounter == 5 {
             question["answers"] = answers
            result.append(question)
            question = [:]
            answers = []
            answerCounter = 0
        }
    }
}

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(jsonString)
```

Save that JSON in the bundle as `data.json` and delete the text file

Now you can decode the JSON into a struct with

```
struct Question : Decodable {
    let question : String
    let answers : [String]
    let correctAnswerIndex : Int
    let number : Int
}


let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Question].self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a your `txt` file by printing `source`. You'll get something like this:

```
Optional("1. A patient with ischemic heart disease has been administered inosine which is an intermediate metabolite in the synthesis of:\n    A. Metalloproteins\n    B. Glycoproteins\n    C. Ketone bodies\n    D. *Purine nucleotides\n    E. Lipoproteins\n\n2. Rates of chemical reactions of the same order are compared by:\n    A. *Constant of chemical reaction rate\n    B. Endpoint of a reaction\n    C. Change in the concentration of the reaction products\n    D. Change in the reactants concentration\n    E. Chemical reaction rate\n\n ...etc)
```

As you can see, Questions are separated by `\n\n`

```
var elements = source?.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")
```

Then you can separate the question and its answers by `\n`

```
let objectsElement = element.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Make sure in your `txt` file that Questions are separated by two newlines, and that question have only one new line between them.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to access elements in the location 0 to 5 of the array objectsElement. So whenever the objectsElement.count < 6 its going to throw `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Seeing your output i think every time objectsElement has only one element in  it.

Comment: How i can fix it?